# Doorbell to buzzer with relay and AC to AC transformer

Tags: ac, transformer, relay, mains

I have the following buzzer and want to use it with a switch by the door.

[image: Buzzer]
Would the following configuration let this work or are there crucial parts missing?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgVezF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A translation of those parameters into English would be helpful.

Comment: ANd possibly swaping 5v and 12v, or using just single psu would lower the cost, or simply using 220vac relay without DC power.

Comment: or use a switch instead of the relay

Comment: @WesleyLee That would be the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS6DKJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A standard doorbell circuit.*

This is how it's normally done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that circuit would work, and there is nothing crucial missing. However, the circuit appears to be much more complex than it needs to be.  Using an AC relay would eliminate most of the components to the left of the relay. The doorbell button could switch power to the relay directly without need for the the resistor, transistor, or diode.  There are even "self-powered" relays which need nothing but the contact-closure from the door button.